# PHP Sessions vs DB Sessions

Tags: php, session

I dabble in PHP. In the projects I've done I always use the database and a cookie to handle sessions. I've seen "session functions" such as session_start() being used also in other sources. I'm just curious, which is better? Should I be using one or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's three ways that I've used through-out time:

1. The traditional `$_COOKIE`-way, meaning that you actually use cookies to store values
2. The "new" `$_SESSION`-way, where you use an associative array that probably relies on a cookie
3. Using `$_SESSION` in conjunction with the DB, making sessions controllable on a user-basis.

I prefer using option #3, as it both enables me to alter sessions "on-the-fly", as well as track the logged in users easier.

Options #3 would play out in the following way (semi-pseudo):

```
<?php
    //Start the session
    session_start();

    //Get the session data
    $_SESSION['user'] = retrieveSessionDataFromDB($_SESSION['user']['unique_id']);

    //Profit
?>
```

Comment: I use a cookie that holds a sesid. I use that sesid(check with useragent, time, etc) as well check for a corresponding row in mysql table named "ses". Somewhat similar to your #3

Comment: I feel that it's a great solution, as you actually can control the sessions from a centralized point (ie a session listing in the administration).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the built in session functions because you don't have to code all the session handling manually. By default the session state is stored in a file, but you can also change it e.g. to the database using [session_set_save_handler](http://You%20should%20use%20the%20built%20in%20session%20methods).

Comment: Fixed link: [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/session_set_save_handler)

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely use PHP Sessions, for a couple of reasons

1. First reason is that PHP Sessions are easily managed with native methods. There are also plenty of libraries that allow very robust Session management, such as Zend_Session
2. PHP Sessions are more scalable. Using MySQL as your data storage will likely be your biggest bottleneck once your application starts to grow. Storing sessions in memory will allow you to scale horizontally to compensate. Storing in the database could put more strain on your database than it needs.

Typically, though, it doesn't matter much for small applications, but if you plan to grow I would definitely use PHP Sessions.